# Stealing something from somebody (grammar)

Tags: grammar

Is the sentence

> "You can steal me money, but you can't [...]"

correct, or is the

> "You can steal money from me, but you can't [...]"

the only correct version?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. It isn't exactly clear what you're asking. Either sentence can be correct, but they mean different things. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help], and [edit] the post to include more detail about what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Hi. I think it's clear what I'm asking, considering the second part of my question. SAME meaning, the second one is correct, is the first one correct.

Comment: You think it is clear, but to others it is not.  Both sentences are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.  Are you asking if they have the same meaning?  Then no.  If you are asking which one is correct, we need more context to know what idea you are trying to express.  Try paraphrasing your intended meaning, or adding a couple of sentence of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Me" is not (normally) a possessive pronoun. In your first sentence, it should be "my".

> You can steal **my** money ...

It's also fine to say

> You can steal money from me.

These are not quite the same thing.  The first is a possessive pronoun telling us *whose* money it is, while the second is an adverb phrase telling us *who* the money is stolen from.

Other examples:

> Please, take **my food** if you're hungry / Please, take **food from me** if you're hungry.
>
> She could rent **my house** if she wanted. / She could rent **the house from me**, if she wanted.

Again, in both these cases the second sentence *implies* but doesn't require that it's my food or my house.  It could be someone else's:

> She could rent **my mother's** house from me, if she wanted.

Related note: In some English dialects (e.g. Irish) the "my" is pronounced "me".  If you are transcribing these dialects you might see it written that way:

> "I went home to see **me mam** for her birthday," he said with a smile.

Comment: Note that "steal me money" as such could be a strangely-ordered variant of "steal money *for* me". I've never seen that, but I have seen similar reorderings before, for emphasis or other rhetorical effect.